# Are questions about Data Science as a field on topic?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question in the main site about a statement I heard in a Data Science Meetup presentation. It was something like "Data scientists work in order to help executives make the correct, data-driven decisions. In the near  future the value of executives is expected to decrease and ours to increase. In the long term we should replace them". I would like to know if people have some -specific- references either against or in favour of that statement.

N.B: I ask for references rather than opinions.

Is this kind of question valid for the main site? Is it valid in the meta? Is it valid somewhere else?

Personally I think similar questions should be part of the main site, since they help build community and answers could educate people on what data science is (and distinct it from SO or CV).

Comment: What would qualify as references for this? News articles? Company reports? The statement itself is an opinion to begin with. If anything, you should be asking the speaker who said this to justify it, or back it with something concrete.

Comment: More or less his whole talk was an argument around this. He is considered quite an expert of the field, at least in the local community. However, I am looking for some external validation/refs, if any. Btw, I suppose many questions imply some kind of opinion. For example, when somebody says "I use classifier X to solve Y", it reflects an opinion,  i.e., that X is the best classifier for Y.

Comment: You gave a perfect example of a question that should be closed as "too broad." Stack Exchange is not a platform for hosting semi-formal debate.

Comment: I ask for a couple of specific references on this very specific statement. No debate, no opinions, nothing too broad.

Comment: The paraphrase contains several distinct, separable statements. The two about expected future value of executives and data scientists *could* be supported by data - but which data? What model? How is "value" defined? *"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."*

Comment: Hm, not sure how more to clarify this. The question is "I need references for X", and X is a very specific topic: "The value of Data Scientists compared to executives". Please don't argue about "X". I try to solve the same questions you ask by getting some references and reading them! I need one or two references on the topic. Too broad answer means there are lots of refs while I can't find any. Thanks.